# Symfony 1.4: How to manipulate the attributeHolder?

Tags: php, session, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have an Attribute called 'admin_module' in myUser attributeHoler and i want to manipulate it...but i don't even get how to access the values stored there.
I know how to get AttributeHolder in an action, but  I don't have a clue, how to access the values in it.
Any help appreciated...thanks in advance. ;)

Edit after answers:

get:

```
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->set('beilagenbuchung.page', 1, 'admin_module');
```

set:

```
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->get('beilagenbuchung.page', null, 'admin_module');
```

Regards

Nils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_user_session) ?

And by the way, you can see all the attribute using the web debug toolbar: config > User > attributeHolder. Key is the namespace used (if you define one).

See also, the [sfUser.class.php](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/user/sfUser.class.php#L267) where the getter are to retrieve attributes.

Comment: Since there is no get method for the AttributeHolder in the ApiDocs, I didn't try it. :D Thanks for your reply. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Out of any context (*meaning `sfAction`, `sfComponent`...*) you can always set attributes like this:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->setAttribute('key', 'value');
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I meant...I just tried it and it doesn't work for me.